# Unable to validate properly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm validating an input from a user in `jquery`. If the input is empty, false is returned and `jquery` code doesn't run and if it contains some text the `jquery` code runs.
Here is an example-

```
function sendm() {
    var valid;
    valid = sendmval();
    if (valid) {
        //jquery code
    }
}

function sendmval() {
    var valid = true;
    if (!$('#message').val()) {
        valid = false;
    } else {}
    return valid;
}
```

This works fine. However the problem occurs when user inputs `blank spaces` only and thus results in running of `jquery` code even on blank input. How can I prevent this ?

Comment: [`$.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)

Comment: because spaces ARE a value: `!" "` in js evaluates to `false`, because a space is true-ish.

Comment: I agree with @MarcB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Since `spaces` count as character so you have to use `$.trim()` of Jquery like below:-*

```
if (!$.trim($('#message').val())) {
        valid = false;
}
```

*For more reference:-*

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: This was the best answer

Comment: Is there more anything like trim?

Comment: @TomCruise i am not crying. I asked you why you did that? if you gave me an explanation you can happily mark any-one, i have no issue with that even now. Mark any-one you want. it's your question BTY

Answer (score 3):

Since space is also a character, simple use [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function of Javascript strings to remove blank space in the beginning and end. Then proceed with your check as usual.

Note: I have changed:

```
if (!$('#message').val())
```

to

```
if (!$('#message').val().trim())
```

See full working code test:

```js
function sendm() {
  var valid;
  valid = sendmval();
  if (valid) {
    alert("valid & sendm");
  }
}

function sendmval() {
  var valid = true;
  if (!$('#message').val().trim()) {
    valid = false;
  } else {}
  return valid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="message">
<button onclick="sendm()">CHECK</button>
```